# ¿Por qué tengo el error: Unable to move, en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un código con el que quiero copiar una imagen a servidor, es el siguiente:

```
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        //$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $destino = "../img/img-services/" . $nombre;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $destino)) {
           $message= "El Archivo ha sido subido correctamente.";


        } else {
           $message= "Lo sentimos, hubo un error subiendo el archivo.";
        }
```

Pero mi archivo PHP me envia el siguiente error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(../img/img-services/pwp-slider.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm/controller/serviceController.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpRrtOq6' to '../img/img-services/pwp-slider.png' in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm/controller/serviceController.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />
```

No se si sea un error del APACHE o de que estoy utilizando macOS para programar.

Esta es la estructura de mis carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo necesitas hacer es entrar a la ruta  o carpeta donde moverás el archivo y darle permisos de escritura

Comment: Hola, si el error dice `Permission denied` probablemente sea por que no tienes permisos de escritura en las carpetas del servidor, para resolverlo si el servidor es linux puedes usar `chmod -R 777 /carpeta`, para mas información puedes revisar [Chmod to a folder and all contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328481/chmod-777-to-a-folder-and-all-contents)

Comment: @the-breaker si quieres agrega tu COMENTARIO como RESPUESTA, para que te de tus puntos de stackoverflow va? si me sirvio tu ayuda.

Comment: @RicardoSauceda lo haría con gusto pero termino mi descanso, tal vez pueda hacerlo mas tarde, de igual forma alguien mas puede dar una respuesta detallada en base a esa información.